# Getting Syntax error in SQL query in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am getting a syntax error, but I am mostly sure I am doing everything right. Could you take a look?

```
String ORDER, DROP, CAR;

            String Statement = "INSERT INTO WORKORDER"
                    + "(ORDER, DROPOFFDATE, COMPLETIONDATE) VALUES "
                    + "( ?, ?, null);";

            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, Statement, "Daisy Imports", 3);
            try {
                PreparedStatement PST = connection.prepareStatement(Statement);
                ORDER = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please assign a order number for this order");
                int ORDERi = Integer.parseInt(ORDER);
                DROP = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the date the car was dropped off (YYYY-MM-DD)");
                CAR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the VIN for the car this work order is for");
                PST.setInt(1, ORDERi);
                PST.setString(2, DROP);
                PST.execute();
```

Comment: I'd consider changing `( ?, ?, null)` to `( ?, ?, ?)` and using `PST.setObject(3, null)` instead

Comment: I just gave that a shot and am getting the same error.

Comment: Please include the exact error in your question. The problem though is with `order`, it needs to be quoted as it is a a reserved word. Use double quotes in most database systems, back ticks in MySQL; so `"ORDER"` or `\`ORDER\``

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the semicolon at the end of your prepared statement.

**Edit:** The problem was that "ORDER" is a reserved word.

Comment: I had originally added that to see if it would work. Removing it didnt fix it.

Comment: change the column name from order then?  Might be a reserved word?  ...Although not sure why it would have let you create the table then.

Comment: It was that. Thats really odd because i used that in other queries, but it didnt break it til i had to use it for inser. thanks

Comment: Asking someone to "try" this in the hopes of fixing the problem, then it's not an answer, its a suggestion. A comment would be more appropriate.

Comment: @dat3450 Thanks.  Although, I don't have comment rights yet, but will keep that in mind.